# Intval function in Laravel eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am doing filter script. User write age_to and I get users with maximum age. The problem is that my in my users table is only full date of birth. How can I get all data? I think intval function is good but I do not know how to use it in mysql query.

```
$user = User::with('user_x')->whereHas('user_x', function($query) use ($request) { 
            $birth_date = Carbon::now()->subYears($request->age_to)->toDateString();

            return $query->where('date_of_birth', '<=', $birth_date); 
        })->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Intval probably won't do what you want, but `Carbon` may. Since you're going for age, then use Carbon's date setters:

```
$birth_date = Carbon::now()->subYears($request->age_from)->toDateString(); // Sets the birth date to today's date minus the requested years
```

Then you can use it in your query:

```
$user = User::with('user_x')->whereHas('user_x', function($query) use ($birth_date) { 
            return $query->where('date_of_birth', '<=',$birth_date); 
        })->get();
```

Comment: I think not. In database i have 1998-10-10 and i have to get that user if age to is for example 20

Comment: Right. So calculating the birth_date, it would take today's date, then subtract 20 years. So that would be `1997-11-01`. So it would look for anyone in the database born on or before 1997-11-01.

Comment: I edited first post. But now i get everything like before

Comment: Okay, if you want to get all of the data from that table, that's a whole other question and negates the answer. You should create a new question with that information, or add to it, instead of completely changing your question.

Comment: Yeah, I want to get all but aga must be to specific date.

Comment: when i do it with integer it works, but i need it in string

Comment: I'm not sure what you're saying here.